# C# StreamWrite to Process not executing on flush

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, process

I'm executing a jar file from a c# process. This is how I start the process and redirect the Input & Output. **Problem indicated at the bottom!**

```
Process process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

if (isLinux)
{
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Servers/" + server.ServerLocation + "/";
}
else
{
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Servers\\" + server.ServerLocation + "\\";
}

process.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms" + server.AllocatedRam + "M -Xmx" + server.AllocatedRam + "M -jar " + '"' + path + '"';
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

LogController.Notice("Server Starting", server.Name);

proc = process;
process.Start();

if (Write.ContainsKey(server.ID))
{
    Write.Remove(server.ID);
    Write.Add(server.ID, process.StandardInput);
}
else
{
    Write.Add(server.ID, process.StandardInput);
}

if (Output.ContainsKey(server.ID))
{
    Output.Remove(server.ID);
    Output.Add(server.ID, process.StandardOutput);
}
else
{
    Output.Add(server.ID, process.StandardOutput);
}
```

Dictionaries

```
public static Dictionary<string, StreamWriter> Write = new Dictionary<string, StreamWriter>();
public static Dictionary<string, StreamReader> Output = new Dictionary<string, StreamReader>();
```

Executing command without closing writer

```
StreamWriter w = ServerController.Write[ID];
w.Write(Command.command);
w.Flush();
```

**^ Flushing this will not execute the write. If I dispose the writer then I cannot execute more than 1 command. The writer has to always be open for writes and be able to execute the write but flushing does not work.**

Comment: Maybe `WriteLine` instead of `Write` may help? Possibly `Flush` is not needed then.

Comment: Thank you! Works